# Does anyone know a good T3 (weblogic) source?

Tags: weblogic

I have just started working using weblogic protocol - T3 and I am really having a rough time finding good info over the internet.

Do you know any source/examples/books?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why are u going to use the T3 protocol for?

Answer (score 1):

http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/weblogic_chap17/index1.html